# Toggle Button appearance on Android 4+

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a small problem. I don't know if it's a real problem or just a bug in the android emulator. Here it is - I have a toggle button in a form, it works just fine but when I run my app on the Nexus 7 emulator to test on large layout, the green indicator of the toggle button doesn't show. Only the text is visible. On my Nexus 4 (4.3) it works just fine (and several other devices with different android versions). Will this happen on a real device or it is just a bug of the emulator?

[image]

Comment: Well, its kind of ambiguous but i would say try to make the height of that button a bit bigger just to make sure that it is not being shrinked or something.

Comment: already did that, the green indicator is not showing again.

Answer (score 0):

Are they on the same version of Android? The version that the Nexus 7 shipped with was 4.1 and your Nexus 4 is apparently 4.3.

If you're using the default ToggleButton style it will look different on different versions of android. If you want it to look the same across multiple versions you could make a selector and set that as the background.

In your ToggleButton xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/myselector"
```

Then create a myselector.xml in your drawables folder and add some conditions. Here's a sample one I have for a checkbox. ToggleButton should look similar:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/star_golden_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/star_gray_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/star_golden" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/star_gray" />
</selector>
```